# Excel VBA Updating Chart Series

Tags: excel, charts, datasource, vba

I have a code the copying the range to a certain cell and change the data source to the chart. the chart has combination chart type, which has stacked columns and `xlLineMarker` with last series(Grand Total). The number of the series collection varies based on user selections(2 or more).

It works, but sometimes the chart doesn't get fully updated like the image attached (displaying empty chart with series name as 'series1, series2, ...). When it happens, The right-click on the chart and  click select data, and then simply selecting any series other than series1 update the chart. not refresh or re-assigning the data source. just selecting 'series2' or others in the data selection windows and click 'cancel', which I suspects that the macro doesn't fully executed...,

am I doing something wrong? or is there any way fully update the chart?

[image: Chart 1]

[image: Chart 2]

```
Sub chtupdate()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer

    Set rng = Range("G37").CurrentRegion

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartArea.ClearContents
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlRows

        n = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count                
        For i = 1 To n - 1
            .SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        Next i    

        .SeriesCollection(n).ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: *"which I suspects that the macro doesn't fully executed"* -- Why don't you verifiy that by stepping in with the debugger? atm the only advice I have in mind is to 1) not `Activate` the chart (no need); 2) disable screen updating during the macro; 3) since you're inside a `With clause`, replace `n = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count` with the simpler `n = .SeriesCollection.Count`

Comment: @Danny Yun try the code in my answer below

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've got rid of Activating chart. I do have code to disable and enable screen updating code between the codes below. I just didn't add that here. As your recommendation, I've used 'Step In' with the debugger. the problem persists. it works at first, but it fails at second. I am not sure why it does work sometimes and doesn't work. And thanks for the tip on '.SeriesCollection.Count'. yes, it's cleaner. Anyway, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, I've added `ChartObject` and `Series` objects variables for an easier and "cleaner" code. Also, to avoid the need of using `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveChart` - a method that be unreliable.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub chtupdate()

Dim MyCht       As ChartObject
Dim Ser         As Series

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

' fully qualify all your Ranges and Cells
With Worksheets("Sheet3") ' <-- replace "Sheet1| with your sheet's name
    Set Rng = .Range("G37").CurrentRegion

    ' set the chart object
    Set MyCht = .ChartObjects("Chart1")
End With

With MyCht
    .Chart.ChartArea.ClearContents
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Rng, PlotBy:=xlRows

    For Each Ser In .Chart.SeriesCollection
        Ser.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    Next Ser

    ' modify the last one
    Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count)
    Ser.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. But It's still same. I have a multiple sheets with one pivot table, one regular table (copied pivot in transpose view), one chart. The reason why I am copying the Pivot Table to a regular table is that Pivot Chart doesn't work in Mac Excel. So I copy pivot table to selected range and set this copied range as chart data source.

Comment: Each Sheet has one or more dropdown buttons. by selecting these drop down buttons, pivot table gets updated (remove existing row field and add selected field to row field / remove existing value item add selected value item to value field / Remove existing column field and add selected field to column field).

Comment: So, I have a codes addRow(),addColumn(), and addValue(). these codes assigned to 'Dropdown' buttons. then once pivot table get updated, I call  copyPivotTable() and chtupdate() codes inside Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate event. the reason why I am using this event to trigger 'chtupdate' is the slicers. I am using slicers to filter, but I can't assign macro to the slicers, so I use pivot table update event. this is one of the reason that I used ActiveSheet instead sheet name. (On Mac, worksheet events don't work, so I added one more buttons to excute 'copy pivot' and 'chtupdate')

Comment: BTW, your codes to update chart is very clean. thank you for that. but it still do same. It works when I switch my dropdown list from one to another. but it has same issue some times. it fully update chart and sometimes shows the blank chart with 'series1', 'series2'...., and again if I open select data pop up window and select the series other than 'series1', then chart get updated fully.